# How to concatenate extra value to output of one command and pass it to another Unix command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, xargs

I have this command

```
grep 'Some pattern' location/*filename* | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '}' -f2 |
grep -v '^$' | head -1
```

The above command is giving me output as some file name, such as:

```
abc.txt
```

Now I want to grep another line from this file abc.txt with matching some specific pattern, so I did this

```
grep 'some pattern' location/*filename* | grep -iv .tar | grep -v backup |
grep -v bkp | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '}' -f2 | head -1 | xargs grep 'some pattern'
```

It's not working because the `abc.txt` file is not present in my current directory.

Can anybody tell me how to append location path to `abc.txt` before passing it to `xargs grep` command?

Comment: Please dont suggest me to write script and store values into some variable and all. I can do that but I can't write script and use variables

Comment: Please post your data, and what you like out of it, and how to get it.  This will help us understand your problem, and make it possible for us to help you.

Comment: @Jotne I cant post data but I can explain it more.. I have files in one directory.. dev/temp/code/steps/ I am getting one file name(abc.txt) from above directory using my first command.
now abc.txt is present in some another directory suppose
dev/temp/text/
now I want to grep one line from this abc.txt like I do in above command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everybody Thanks for your suggestion.. any how I also found some solution for my problem..

FYI

here is what I used..

```
echo "dev/temp/text/"$(grep 'Some pattern' location/*filename* | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '}' -f2 | grep -v '^$' | head -1) | xarg grep 'some pattern'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
grep 'some pattern' location/*filename* | grep -iv .tar | grep -v backup |
grep -v bkp | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '}' -f2 | head -1 | xargs |
sed 's#.*#/path/to/dir/&#g' | xargs grep 'some pattern'
```

Comment: Why the empty `xargs`?

Answer (score 0):

If `cmd` produces output "bar", but you want "foobar", you can simply do:

```
printf foo; cmd
```

In your case, if you want to prepend `/p/a/t/h` to your output, just do:

```
{ printf /p/a/t/h/; grep 'some pattern' filename | ... | head -1; } | xargs ...
```

But you're probably better off just replacing the `head -1` with `sed -e 1s@^@/p/a/t/h/@ -e 1q`

Answer (score 0):

Superficially, if the first command sequence gives you the name of a file in some directory, you need to use `find` to get the path name to the file:

```
find . -type f -name $(grep 'Some pattern' location/*filename* | cut -d ' ' -f2 |
                       cut -d '}' -f2 | grep -v '^$' | head -1) \
     -exec grep 'some pattern' {} +
```

You don't need a backslash after the first line (though it would do no harm); you do need the backslash after the second line.  You might specify a different starting point than `.` for the search.

Comment: I have file path so no need to find it.. It will increase time .. I just need to append file path and use it to next command.. any way thankyou as you answer give me hint and I found my solution. Please check my answer

Comment: If you know the path, then you just write `grep 'some pattern' path/to/abc.txt`, don't you?

Comment: but I am getting abc.txt from another command... as mention in my question

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

```
... | head -1 | sed 's,^,location/,' | xargs grep 'some pattern'
```

or

```
... | head -1 | xargs -I FILE grep 'some pattern' location/FILE
```